# UITableView - footer for section - iPhoneX

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have problem with iPhone and `UITableView` section footer. It is being "hidden" behind the top cut-out section.

I have this code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        var content = "some long text"


        let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 40))

        let explanationLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 50))
        explanationLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)
        explanationLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        explanationLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        explanationLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        explanationLabel.text = content
        footerView.addSubview(explanationLabel)
        return footerView
    }
```

My `UITableViewController` is added from storyboard and safe areas are set. I have no problem with table lines, only with section footer.

Comment: Is this a problem you are only experiencing on the iPhone X? or iPhone in general?

Comment: Only iPhoneX.. the other have "regular" screen

Comment: I'm facing something similar with even just `titleForFooter`. I strongly believe it's an iPhone X bug since it's never happened in years on any iOS device.

Comment: @keeshux See my answer, I have solved it this way

Comment: @MartinPerry actually I also found a simple fix in the meantime, unless I miss any possible scenario. Posting my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have solved the problem with this code, added after `footerView.addSubview(explanationLabel)`:

```
explanationLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let guide = footerView.safeAreaLayoutGuide

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        explanationLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.topAnchor),
        explanationLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        explanationLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        explanationLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  footerView.bottomAnchor)
   ])
}
else {        
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        explanationLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.topAnchor),
        explanationLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        explanationLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        explanationLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  footerView.bottomAnchor)
    ])
}
```